# How to access an array of chars (string) at the character before the null char

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am storing strings within a 1D array set to a maximum size, say 50.

`char array[50];`

Within this array I fill it using putchar, but do not use every cell within the array. If the strings I enter into the array are variable (i.e `hello` or `hello world!`), how can I access the last character within the array to compare the first and last characters, the 2nd and 2nd last, etc?

Here is my code to fill the array with characters:

```
    while (((c = getchar()) != EOF) && (c != '\n')) //getchars while not EOF or null
    {
        s[i] = c; // index 0  = getchar
        i++; // loop through every index until terminated
    }
    s[i] = '\0'; // add null character to last cell.
```

With integer arrays I would just use the index of the size minus 1, etc, but there are a different number of empty cells when I enter a different string.

Comment: `strlen` is returning the string length. Or use your `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
   int j=0,len;
   for(int k=0;a[k]!='\0';k++)        // loop until a[k] is not '\0'
   {
       j++;                           // increment j (at last gives length of string )
   }
   len=j;                            // initialize len with value of j
  for(i=0;i<len;i++){                // loop from i to len
    if(s[i]==s[j]){                  // compare value at index i and len 
           // do something
      }
    j--;                            // decrement j
 }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using strlen?

Comment: @Finlandia_C  Yes , it is possible but is there any specific reason ?

Comment: @Finlandia_C: You build your string withb `getchar` and keep track of its length in `i`. After reading is done and you have added your null terminator, `i` has the value of `strlen(s)`.

Comment: @Finlandia_C  I have updated the code and without `strlen`.

Comment: Ahhh that's it. I had jotted down a[]!= '\0' but wasn't sure whether it was right! Thank you! :)

Comment: @Finlandia_C  Welcome :)

Comment: Instead of `int j=0, len; for(int k=0;a[k]!='\0';k++) { j++; } len = j;` could simplify to `int len; while (a[len]) len++;` or even `int len = i;`.